# Untrack a file from a git branch without switching to the branch

Tags: git, version-control, github

i have some files i don't need to be tracked (mostly uploaded images) However i do need them there... in the working directory

lets call it `imageFolder`

my `.gitignore` didn't have the line `**/imageFolder` some time ago... 
so some of the images are being tracked...

in the development process i have created a couple of branches with `imageFolder` tracked
lets say we have 3 branches

- master
- cleanBranch
- dirtyBranch

right now i have cleanBranch checked out
i fixed this branch with `git rm -r --cached imagesFolder` and added `**/imagesFolder` to the `.gitignore`

everything is perfectly fine :) and i am a happy camper...

**PROBLEM**

when i try to switch to dirtyBranch that still has those images tracked git says

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
imageFolder/img1.jpg
imageFolder/img2.jpg
...
...
Aborting
```

it does't let me switch to the other branch so i can run `git rm -r --cached` and fix the `.gitignore`

is there a way to untrack those images from a branch that you don't have checked out... 
or my train of though is wrong and i should take a different approach to resolving this issue

I do need those images to be there in the folder

other than the images the 2 branches look quite different...

i am a git noob take it easy on me hehe :)
thank you..

Comment: Clone your repo and do the cleanup there, where you have a clean working copy and/or can afford overwriting stuff, then push it back to your normal repo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the files out, which will remove the error.  Then after you've done the cleanup, you can move them back in.